# Installing opencv on openshift for java development

Tags: java, opencv, makefile, openshift

I am trying to install opencv on openshift. following the post mentioned here

http://codingexodus.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-install-opencv-on-openshift.html

I am developing in java so i have installed jdk1.8 and apache ant into the $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR 
I had to install apache ant also so i did the same again in the $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR

my JAVA_HOME is set to the jdk and even ANT_HOME is also pointing to the right place
JAVA_HOME="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0_05"

I am doing a cmake in the end to generate the makefile with the command

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
```

going through the cmake output i do see that for java it has found the ant, jni etc. finally when i execute a

```
make 
make install
```

i get the error

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

there is no make file generated. what am missing.